# Query select columns from row based upon cell value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking to pull certain cells from a row based upon the date(todays) which is in cell I1 on Dashboard. I would like to pull the row from Schedule but only return the team name which is in columns AH and AW.

I tried this

```
=QUERY(Schedule!A:BU,"select AH, AW Where Schedule!A:A = '"&I2&"'")
```

Its shooting an error of "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered "  "Schedule "" at line 1, column 21. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...
"

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bWyFiPsOkmskPNNePvPrbaL2oHAht9QS-lFuwAlSS9o/edit

Comment: `=QUERY(Schedule!A1:BU500,"select AH, AW where A:A = '"&I2&"'")`

Comment: its still giving off the "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "A "" at line 1, column 21. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ..." error and also displays a "-" under the error in cell g3

Comment: Added a link to the sheet. Thought I did originally. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added a working formula to your sheet

```
=filter({Schedule!AH:AH,Schedule!AW:AW},TO_DATE(INT(left(Schedule!D:D,10)))=I1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The values in column `Schedule!A2:A` are not dates but text strings that look like dates. You can search them in a `query()` if you convert the search key in cell `I1` to a text string with `to_text()`, like this:

`=query(Schedule!A1:BU, "select AH, AW where A = '" & to_text(I1) & "' ", 1)`